# How to use dynamically linked dll in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, taglib-sharp

I imported the [taglib-sharp dll](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.1.0.0/) (that had been copied to the bin/debug folder of my project) in my C# application and then used types and methods from the library in the following way:

```
using TagLib;

private void method()
{
    TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create("C:\\temp\\some.mp3");
    TagLib.Tag tag = file.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2);
}
```

Now I want to link the dll dynamically. How can I implement the same functional in this case?

That, what I've tried:

```
using System.Reflection

private void method()
{
    Assembly TagLib = Assembly.Load("taglib-sharp");
        
    Type TagLibFile = TagLib.GetType("File");
    dynamic LibFile = Activator.CreateInstance(TagLibFile);
    
    TagLibFile file = LibFile.Create("c:\\temp\\some.mp3");
}
```

In this implementation, VisualStudio says that I can't use the tagLibFile variable as a type. I supposed that when I get a type from dll, I will be able to create variables of this type.

By the way, is this approach is correct?

P.S. Also, I tried to use the [invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but I was not sure what object I should pass as a first argument.

## UPD

Based on @nawfal's awnser below, I've got the following working code:

```
using System.Reflection

private void method()
{
    Assembly TagLib = Assembly.Load("taglib-sharp");

    // get the File type
    var fileType = TagLib.GetType("TagLib.File");
    // get the overloaded File.Create method
    var createMethod = fileType.GetMethod("Create", new[] { typeof(string) });

    // get the TagTypes method that contains Id3v2 field
    Type tagTypes = TagLib.GetType("TagLib.TagTypes");
    // get the overloaded File.GetTag method
    var getTagMethod = fileType.GetMethod("GetTag", new[] {tagTypes});
    // obtain the file
    dynamic file = createMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { "C:\\temp\\some.mp3" });
    // obtain the Id3v2 field value
    FieldInfo Id3TagField = tagTypes.GetField("Id3v2");
    var Id3Tag = Id3TagField.GetValue(tagTypes);

    // obtain the actual tag of the file
    var tag = getTagMethod.Invoke(file, new[] { Id3Tag });
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with DLLs. You are using reflection to load a type at *runtime*. The type is *not* available at compile time. The only thing available is a variable named `TagLibFile` which can't be used as a type obviously

Comment: I see what you mean

Comment: Why do you want it to be dynamic? May be there is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure that I need it dynamic. I am newbie in open source coding and creating application based on the TagLib library. This library uses the LGPL license. According to this license, as I understand, I can use it in any kind of applications, but I must import this library dynamically. So that is why I am trying to implement this. (=

Comment: @FillFreeman I am not sure of a license like that. I think it's worth asking that license question online and get help and if possible reference the library from VS. DLLs are dynamically linked, may the license is talking about that. It is different from *dynamically loading* as you are doing now. Currently your code is horrible :)

Comment: @nawfal, yeah, you're right, it is awful, but it works. About the license: according to [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86142/what-exactly-do-i-need-to-do-if-i-use-a-lgpl-licenced-library), it is enough to share project's code, and this is what I'm going to do. So, I will not use this solution. At least I've learnt how to do it! (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```
private void method()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("taglib");
    var type = assembly.GetType("namespace.File"); // namespace qualified class name
    // assuming you only have one Create method, otherwise use reflection to resolve overloads
    var method = type.GetMethod("Create");

    dynamic file = method.Invoke(null, new[] { "C:\\temp\\some.mp3" }); // null for static methods
    var tag = file.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2); // not sure if you can pass those params, 
                                                  // may be do reflection to get them too
}
```

Kindly rethink if you want it to be dynamic. If you can reference the dll then you can still get the benefits of strong typing.

Answer (score 0):

Save it as object.

```
object file = LibFile.Create(fi.FullName);
```

Should work.

Dynamic loading dlls works much different.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.

Comment: When I use object as a type, I cannot use methods of the file instance (for example file.GetTag), because compiller does not see members of the file class. I updated my example, to show it.